# Como se consome rotas personalizadas com ember?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, api, emberjs

Minha api rails possui a rota usuarios/mim que retorna os dados do usuário atual, tá escrito assim:

```
  #routes
  resources :usuarios do
    get :mim, on: :collection
  end

  #controller
  def mim
    render json: usuario_atual
  end
```

Como posso acessar essa rota da api com o ember para obter os dados do usuário?

Comment: Encontrei a solução aqui http://www.thegreatcodeadventure.com/creating-a-current-user-property-in-ember/ #grato

Answer (score 1):

O formato mais simples seria:

```
// rota: user.js
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Route.extend({
  model() {
    return Ember.$.ajax('http://host/user/min');
  }
});
```

E no template user.hbs

```
Nome: {{model.name}}
```

Comment: Ele não fica gerenciado pelo ember-data utilizando chamada ajax.

Answer (score 0):

Você deve criar um `adapter` para seu model. Ele pode customizar a caminho.

```
import DS from 'ember-data';
import { underscore } from '@ember/string';

export default DS.JSONAPIAdapter.extend({
  pathForType(type) {
    return '/autenticacao';
  }
});
```

Na sua rota então você pesquisa o model

```
model() {
    return this.store.findeRecord('me');
    // ira fazer uma requisicao para host/autenticacao/me

}
```

https://guides.emberjs.com/release/models/customizing-adapters/#toc_path-customization